# Issue with basic while, if, and print statement (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

```
threenum = eval(input("Enter 3 Numbers: "))

n1 = threenum[0]
n2 = threenum[1]
n3 = threenum[2]

while n1<=n2:
    if n1%n3==0
        print(n1)
        n1=n1+1
    elif n1%n3!=0
        n1=n1+1
```

I keep getting a Syntax Error highlighting the n1 in print(n1).
I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you need to end the if/elif statements with a colon:

```
if n1%n3==0:
    print(n1)
    n1=n1+1
elif n1%n3!=0:
    n1=n1+1
```

Comment: I just facepalmed. Thank you so much. How could I miss such a simple mistake.